# What does "true ===" without a variable do?

Tags: javascript, azure

The following code is not mine. Created by Microsoft Azure for window.appInsights. This code works in Edge & IE, but fails in Chrome (throws "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&&'" in the console). Firefox complains about it, but works anyway.

Can someone explain to me what this is doing (attempting to do)? I've not seen something like this before.

`if (true ===  && "" !== "") {`

UPDATE
Thank you all for your answers. I thought it was poorly written code, but wanted to be sure it didn't contain a coding shorthand I wasn't aware of. Your answers cleared that up for me !

Comment: That just looks like a syntax error to me. Firefox also throws an error on it for me, it doesn't "work anyway". Even if the first half made sense, the second half of the condition is `"" !== ""` which is always false, so whatever it's trying to do, it will never evaluate to true anyway.

Comment: I've pasted `if (true ===  && "" !== "") { console.log('x'); }` in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, and all three of them give a syntax error.

Comment: Found an IE on some computer, gives syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is a mistake . It shouldn't work. `===` is a binary operator and therefore expects 2 operands not 1. `&&` is not an expression neither a valid identifier.

Read it in english. `if true is strictly equal to or empty string is strictly not equal to empty string`

---

i wonder what `"" !== ""` is trying to do since it will always evaluate to false lol